# Dividir dos INT y que salga en decimales o enteros SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3, sentencias

Buenas tengo un problema en el sqlite.

Select (A+B)/2 => aquí los valores en los paréntesis son Integer, la solución que he visto es que unos de los valores los multiplique *1.0 pero solo funciona en algunos casos prácticos como el siguiente enunciado

Select ((70*1.0)+55)/2 => saldría tal cual lo quiero 62.5

select ((60*1.0)+38)/2 => pero en algunos casos como este el valor saldría 49.0 cuando solo tendría que salir el valor entero.

espero alguien tenga una mejor solución a esto, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lo que mostras es un problema de formato. El problema se da donde? porque lo que veas adentro de la DB no cuenta...

Comment: O salen flotantes o salen enteros de tu división, pero no puedes pretender que salga entero si haces conversión a flotante y viceversa. Mi sugerencia: maneja todo como flotante (el resultado) y das formato al resultado para mostrar hasta 1 o 2 decimales. Pero pretender devolver un entero basado en que sus valores decimales parecen un cero es cuando menos una tarea que mejor se la delegas a la presentación y no al motor de Base de Datos.